# Can 6x6 Glue Lamm Post be installed on the exterior and be exposed to the weather?

Tags: deck

Can I use a 6x6 glue lamm post as a support post for an upper deck and can this type of post be exposed to the outside elements (rain, snow, etc..)

Answer (score 2):

It must be an exterior/wet use rated beam, [like this one from Boise](http://seek.autodesk.com/product/latest/agg/boisecascadellc/Boise-Cascade-LLC/Boise08)  If you are going to bury one end of it, it must meet one of the exterior ground contact categories.  You should discuss this with your inspector and list it on your permit submission drawing, so there are no surprises during inspection.

The [AWPA](http://www.awpa.com/) rates wood by its usage category, you should pick a glulam assembly that will meet one or more of the various **EXTERIOR** categories:

> Use Category  Brief Description

- UC1    Interior Dry
- UC2    Interior Damp
- UC3A   Exterior Above Ground, Coated with Rapid Water Runoff
- UC3B   Exterior Above Ground, Uncoated or Poor Water Runoff
- UC4A   Ground Contact, General Use
- UC4B   Ground Contact, Heavy Duty
- UC4C   Ground Contact, Extreme Duty
- UC5A   Marine Use, Northern Waters (Salt or Brackish Water)
- UC5B   Marine Use, Central Waters (Salt or Brackish Water)
- UC5C   Marine Use, Southern Waters (Salt or Brackish Water)
- UCFA   Interior Above Ground Fire Protection
- UCFB   Exterior Above Ground Fire Protection